# Multiple dex files define error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I know this question has been asked number of times but none of the solutions provided has worked for me hence I am asking a fresh one. I am getting the above-mentioned error after importing my project from Eclipse to Android Studion. Below is my build.gradle file. As you can see, I have commented most of my libs but still no workaround. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false

compileOptions {
    encoding "UTF-8"
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.yyy"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
//compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.19.1.jar')
//compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.19.1.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-services-youtube-v3-rev126-1.19.1.jar')
//compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.19.0.jar')
//compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.19.0.jar')
//compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.17.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.17.0-rc.jar')
//compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-java6-1.17.0-rc.jar')
//compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-jetty-1.17.0-rc.jar')
//compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-servlet-1.17.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar')
//compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1.jar')
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.2'
compile files('libs/picasso-2.3.4.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile project(':CircularImageView')
//compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.3.0'
compile project(':CountryPicker')
compile project(':PullToRefreshListView')
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0@aar') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'bolts'
}
}
```

**The error I am getting:**

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/util/StreamingContent
```

Comment: You are using different version of this class com/google/api/client/util/StreamingContent.
Check your jars. You can replace a lot of them with a gradle dependency.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, which of my dependencies have that class? And please how can I replace them with the gradle dependency? I am new to gradle so I am trying to find my footing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Gabriele for the direction. I solved this problem by removing google-api-client-1.19.1.jar which turns out that though it was commented out, it still existed in the libs folder so I had to manually delete it from the project. I got to know this when I run gradle -dependencies from AS terminal.